# Vue.js computed properties, filter by object key

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm working with an object containing multiple network interfaces with the interfaces' names as keys and then interfaces' informations as values :

[image]

What I would like to do is a Vue.js computed property to filter this object by Keys and create arrays that contain all GigabitEthernet separately for example so I can iterate over it in my template.

I thinked about using Regex, here is the one that I use and match the interfaces I want to put in a separate array :

`const regex = /^(Te|GigabitEthernet|FastEthernet)+\s?([0-9]+\/){0,}[0-9]+$/g;`

The problem is that the main object received from API isn't an array so I can't use find() or filter() functions over it...

If anyone as any idea it would be nice, thanks !

EDIT :

After trying Jaromanda's solution :

[image]

It returns only 1 line out of 2...

Here is the code :

```
const regex = /^(Ten|GigabitEthernet|FastEthernet)\d+[/]?[\d+]?[/]?[\d+]?[.]?[\d+]?[/]?[\d+]?[/]?[\d+]?[:]?[\d+]?$/g;
      var rslt = {};
      Object.fromEntries(
        Object.entries(this.cmdResult).filter(([key, value]) => {
          if (regex.test(key)) {
            rslt[key] = value;
          }
        })
      );
      return rslt;
```

Here is a screenshot of current output at the left and expected output at the right :

[image]

EDIT 2 :

Here is what happens when I console log the regex results with the associated key :

[image]

As you can see only 1 out of 2 is true...

Comment: use `Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(object).filter(([key, value]) => your code to filter))`

Comment: Wow that's exactly what I needed, thanks !

Comment: It's working but there's only 1 problem, it returns only 1 line out of 2, can you check my edit please?

Comment: What do you mean it only returns 1 line out of 2?

Comment: GigabitEthernet1/0/4 is missing, GigabitEthernet1/0/28 is too... etc.. even if it matches the regex

Comment: I added a screenshot

Comment: [`test`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/test) will advance the [`lastIndex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/lastIndex) property of the regex when used with the global flag (`g`). For this reason the next match fails, because it starts of too far into the string to find a match. Either remove the `g` flag from the regex, create a new regex for each test or reset the `lastIndex` property to `0` before each `test`.

Comment: In fact, it's working now, thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is other solution, using map.

```js
const cmdResult = {
  "GigabitEthernet1/0/2": {name: ""},
  "GigabitEthernet1/0/3": {name: ""},
  "GigabitEthernet1/0/4": {name: ""}


}
const regex = /(GigabitEthernet||FastEthernet\d+(\.\d)*)/i;
const rslt = {};
Object.keys(cmdResult)
  .filter((key) => regex.test(key))
  .map(prop => rslt[prop] = cmdResult[prop])
    
console.log(rslt);
```

Comment: It's still not working... Can you please check my last edit, I added a screenshot, it's really strange, even in your code snippet GigabitEthernet1/0/3 is missing...

Comment: @ryuzak1, Ok, the problem is with the regex pattern. What do you want to filter, props that contains GigabitEthernet, FastEthernet..???

Comment: Yes, in this case FastEthernet, GigabitEthernet, In other words i don't want the last two Vlan to be in the result, but what's weird here is when I test the regex with an online regex tester, the keys that returned false in my code are working with the tester

Comment: @ryuzak1, check the new regex pattern.

Comment: Thanks ! I just replaced g by i at the end of the regex as 3limin4t0r mentionned and it's now working